# vs code , сниппеты, шаблоны, быстрый ввод классов и атрибутов

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

недавно начал учиться веб разработке, и столкнулся с некоторыми непонятными моментами:

1. какие есть вменяемые сниппеты или шаблоны чтобы писать элементарные конструкции, например если хочу сделать элементарную конструкцию контейнера

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

недавно начал учиться веб разработке, и столкнулся с некоторыми непонятными моментами:

какие есть вменяемые сниппеты или шаблоны чтобы писать элементарные конструкции, например если хочу сделать элементарную конструкцию контейнера

я когда пытаюсь ввести cont или .cont и потом ctrl+space то подобного автоматом не предлагается

установлен emmet , и при вводе .cont создаётся блок с классом "cont" , что естественно не то

Винда 10, проекты и система всё на хорошем ssd nvme , с подгрузкой текстового файла проблем быть не должно.

Буду признателен за советы от бывалых, с организацией процесса автоматизации ввода кода. Может быть есть расширения хорошие, о которых я пока не знаю, может редактор кода выбрал неправильный, может есть редакторы где никакие расширения ставить ненужно и всё работает из коробки интуитивно-понятно?

Comment: Данный вопрос уже задавался. Разбейте и сфокусируйтесь на одном вопросе, чтобы можно было дать объективный ответ. Голосую за закрытие, за игнрорирование правил второй раз

Comment: у думал половину оставить , и этого достаточно
отредактировал
старый вопрос так же удалён
так же почему вы говорите за игнорирование "второй раз" ?

Comment: я уже не первый раз вижу этот вопрос, и уже второй раз оставляю подобный комментарий

Comment: вопрос откорректировал, оставил один

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: "при вводе .cont создаётся блок с классом "cont" , что естественно не то"..  Не то - это ваши ожидания... Можно свои сниппеты написать, "вменяемые" чтобы было то..